# Is it possible to force the debugger to show the structure fields in its own way?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, clion, vscode-debugger

I keep a linked list in memory:

```cpp
struct list {
  int value;
  list *nxt;
};
```

In the debugger, for example, Clion, I see its pointer to the next element as a structure and can view it:

[image: list in debugger]

Now I want to serialize this list into a file, and make the pointers an offset in the file. The structure being written to the file is now as follows:

```cpp
typedef int64_t my_offset_t;
struct file_list {
  int value;
  my_offset_t nxt;
};
```

[image: file_list in debugger]

And now I obviously can't move on to the next element.

I can declare a method that will return the structure I need, but then I will have to write something like `a->GetNext()->GetNext()->...` in the debugger. But I want it to look like an ordinary field in the structure, which I can see as in the first image.

Is it possible in Clion/VS Code/... make me interpret such a field as a pointer, but so that I can describe the logic of its dereference myself?
Maybe some special classes, annotations, magic methods,...?

Comment: Generic serialization is *hard*, please don't attempt it yourself. Use a library or framework that already implement it properly instead of spending days, weeks or even months to get something almost working.

Comment: Both IDEs support extensions/plugins, but I'm not sure something like this exists. Worst case, you can write your own.

Comment: CLion does appear to have Natvis support.

Comment: I understand that Natvis is only available for Windows? upd: wow, vsc seems to support on all systems. There is no such thing in Clion on macOS